# If the electron of a hydrogen atom transitions from energy level n=5 to n=3, which level corresponds to n1 and which level corresponds to n2

Tags: quantum-chemistry

which level corresponds to n1 and which level corresponds to n2 in the Rydberg equation?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry Stack Exchange! Please add what you have attempted towards solving the problem into the body of your question.  For more information, see the site's [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) for how to ask homework questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$\bar\nu=\bar R(1/3^2-1/5^2){}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$